# Get the id of last product image to show it as a background on frontend - Prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: image, product, prestashop-1.7

Do you know if it's possible to retrieve the id of last image added on backend product page (see attachment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks9Xm.jpg) to show it on frontend?

I done it on prestashop 1.6 like this -> {$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'new_img_details')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}

but I don't know how to do it on prestashop 1.7.6

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **id_image** in last position with a query in your PHP module / controller :

```
$lastIdImage = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT id_image FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'image 
WHERE id_product = '.$your_id_product.' ORDER BY position DESC');
```

Then you can easily retrieve the link with the **getImageLink** method.

Comment: Hi,  and what is exactly the file (php) to edit?
thank you

Comment: In your request you did not mentioned where you need to have this data, but provided that you need it in the product page you could edit/extend /controllers/front/ProductController.php to assign a custom variable in assignImages method or, in a cleaner way, create a module and return the data in a js variable with a tpl through the "displayproductadditionalinfo" hook